What does the word "well" mean in the last line of Shakespeare's Sonnet 73?
Shakespeare's Sonnet 73, "That time of year thou mayst in me behold", spends its first 12 lines comparing different types of the passage of time (such as seasons and days) to human mortality, with all these types of aging and decay "thou mayst in me behold". Then we have the ending rhyming couplet:

This thou perceiv'st, which makes thy love more strong,
To love that well which thou must leave ere long.

I'm having trouble parsing the placement of the word "well" in the last line. If it means "to love well", why is it placed after "that"? With the placement after "that", the "well" then - to me - becomes associated with the speaker ("which thou must leave ere long"). I'm not sure how that makes much sense either, though; my thought was that "well which" could then mean "which likely", but that's still a rather awkward reading.
What is the word "well" doing in this line?

My interpretation is that "well" is indeed an adverb modifying "love". This makes grammatical sense, as it's fine for an adverb modifying a transitive verb to come after the object of the verb (cf. e.g. "To love that thing deeply which thou must leave ere long", which would be perfectly clear and valid despite "well" not immediately following "love").
The reason why it's placed after "that" is probably for scansion. If the line were "To love well that which thou must leave ere long", it wouldn't be iambic pentameter. As-is, it is.

Yes, and it probably is a holdover from French: aimer bien or bien aimer. Someone removed my comment under the question. I believe it is relevant. love well functions like a separable phrasal verb.

As E. A. Abbott noted in A Shakespearian Grammar, more specifically in entry "420. Transposition of Adverbs",

The Elizabethan authors allowed themselves great licence in this respect.

However, he doesn't give examples of the transposition of "well".
The couplet essentially means, "You see this [i.e. that I am growing old], so your love grows stronger, to love well that which you will need to forgo (or depart from) ere long."
The referent of "that" is the poem's speaker or the hearer's life. In other words, the poet is telling the addressee to love him well or to love life well.
None of the editions I have consulted say anything about the order of "well" in the last line.
As Rand al'Thor already mentioned in his answer, the word order is most likely related to scansion. The current word order allows the following perfectly iambic scansion:

To lóve that wéll which thóu must léave ere lóng.

Moving "well" before "that" would imply a shift in emphasis if we were to retain the iambic metre:

To lóve well thát which thóu must léave ere lóng.

This emphasises the object of love rather than the manner of loving. If we interpret "that" as the poem's speaker, the sonnet becomes more self-centred. If we interpret "that" as the addressee's life, the result sounds rather like "carpe diem". These shifts in the poem's meaning seem significant enough to justify the transposition of the adverb.
Works consulted:

Abbott, E. A.: A Shakespearian Grammar. New edition. London: Macmillan, 1971.
Shakespeare: All the Sonnets of Shakespeare. Edited by Paul Edmondson and Stanley Wells. Cambridge University Press, 2020. (This edition is unusual in that it attempts to order the sonnets in the order in which they might have been written. It has relatively few annotations.)
Shakespeare: The Complete Sonnets and Poems. Edited by Colin Burrow. Oxford University Press, 2002. (This edition has very detailed annotations.)
Shakespeare: The Sonnets and A Lover's Complaint. Edited by John Kerrigan. Penguin, 1986. (This edition has very detailed annotations.)
Willen, Gerard; Reed, Victor B. (editors): A Casebook on Shakespeare's Sonnets. New York: Thomas Y. Crowell, 1964. (An annotated edition of the sonnets followed by essays and explications.)

